# String match in python pandas dataframe when there is different possibilities

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOLW5.png)

I have a Dataframe (300,000 rows) with 4 columns. I have a column "Model" where I have the following sample values.

- 1)CPL40AUP50(B,W)(Blank ,EM, PCEM, MSEM) 2)CPL40AUP50(B,W) (400, MS)
  3)CPL40AUP50(B,W)PC 4)CPL40AUP50(B,W)PCMS     5)CPL40AUP50[B,W][Blank,
  400] 6)CPL40AUP XXXX XXXXX

In the model field, any value like (A, B) means it can be either A or B.
For example, field 2 means, 4 combinations are possible
CPL40AUP50B400
CPL40AUP50BMS
CPL40AUP50W400
CPL40AUP50WMS
and field 6 means CPL 40 AUP "XXXX" "XXXXX" - anytime there is more than 2 continuous XXX, that means any character is accepted in those positions. Number of XXX = number of characters in that place

Sample dataframe is attached.

Attaching the sample as a dictionary

{'Model No.': {152001: 'CPL40AUP50(B,W)(Blank ,EM, PCEM, MSEM)',
  152103: 'CPL40AUP50(B,W) (400, MS)',
  152192: 'CPL40AUP50(B,W)PC',
  152196: 'CPL40AUP50(B,W)PCMS',
  291083: 'CPL40AUP50[B,W][Blank, 400]'},
 'Product Id': {152001: 'PGK58TGD',
  152103: 'P5QBAPTD',
  152192: 'PFNJED7R',
  152196: 'PYSCGR1W',
  291083: 'PH57RZA3'},
 'Reported CCT': {152001: 5000.0,
  152103: 5000.0,
  152192: 5000.0,
  152196: 5000.0,
  291083: 5000.0},
 'Reported Wattage': {152001: 41.07,
  152103: 41.07,
  152192: 41.07,
  152196: 41.07,
  291083: 40.0}}

**Part 1**
I want to search for a model number, that is stored in a variable.
a=CPL40AUP50B400 in this column, and return the entire row, where this possible combination could exist.
I want only the exact search term to be found and print the row, not a partial string match

I replaced all "[]" square brackets into parenthesis "()"
I replaced all "," comma into '|'

I did this in the thought of using regex functions. But I am not able to proceed.

**Part 2** 
To find when there is XXX. If there is an XXX, it means there can be any character instead of XXX.

Example :    6)CPL40AUP XXXX XXXXX

Means, CPL40AUP AAAA AAAAA or CPL40AUP BBBB 11111

Anything can come in place of XXX's.So I have to find the row where there is a model number that matches with all other character's except for the XXX's

Comment: Please post the sample from your DataFrame as text i.e. use df.to_dict() and post that.

Answer (score 0):

First, setting up a DataFrame to test on:

```
import pandas as pd
model = ["CPL40AUP50(B,W)(Blank ,EM, PCEM, MSEM) ", "CPL40AUP50(B,W) (400, MS) ", "CPL40AUP50(B,W)PC ", "CPL40AUP50(B,W)PCMS ", "CPL40AUP50[B,W][Blank, 400] ", "CPL40AUP XXXX XXXXX"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Model': model, 'Wattage': range(40, 46)})
```

For the first question, getting the rows that include a certain string (e.g. "PC"), do the following:

```
df[ df['Model'].str.contains("PC") ]
```

`str.contains("PC")` returns a boolean Series that is True if that row contains "PC" in the 'Model' field. Then `df[ mask ]` returns the rows where mask is True.

"PC" is a regular expression pattern, not just literal letters. So for your second question, the following will get any of the rows that contain two or more consecutive X charracters:

```
df[ df['Model'].str.contains("XX+") ]
```

Comment: This is not what is wanted, contains "PC" will return 1000's of results. I want a specific one, which is a possible model number